# Micrsoft Dynamics CRM: Facing troubling while executing js web resouce for crm button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, crm-ribbon-workbench

I created a button in an account form entity by ribbon workbench and then I tried to create a javascript code.  When executed the code is just fetching the account id and showing that id in the alert and then I registered that file to that button by ribbon workbench action command.
I wrote the below code, please let me know what is wrong with that.

I am expecting an alert box with that id, but nothing is happening

The code is below:

```
fetch = {

    fetchingacountid: function(executionContext){

        var formContext = Xrm.Page.context.getFormContext();
        var accountId = formContext.data.entity.getId();
        alert("The ID of the current account is: " + accountId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you might have missed to add the `PrimaryControl` CRM parameter in ribbon command. Then you don’t need `Xrm.Page`, instead you will get the context directly in the first parameter `executionContext`. [Read more](https://d365demystified.com/2020/09/22/pass-execution-context-to-js-script-function-as-a-parameter-from-a-ribbon-button-in-dynamics-365-ribbon-workbench/)

[image]